# How to use sleep in swift 2.2

Tags: swift, sleep

When I use sleep(1), my app sleeps through the whole loop instead of 1 sec.
After 90 sec. the labels get updated instead of every sec.

code:

```
    while time < 90 {
        let goal = Int(arc4random_uniform(MAX) + MIN)

        if goal < 5 {
            scoreA = scoreA + 1
        } else if goal > 15 {
            scoreB = scoreB + 1
        }

        time = time + 1
        scoreLabel.text = "\(scoreA) - \(scoreB)"
        timeLabel.text = "\(time) min."
        sleep(1)
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you are updating the labels from a background thread, which you're not supposed to do.

Comment: @Codo why do you think he does?

Comment: I've seen this kind of strange delay myself. When I debugged the problem I found that code updating the UI was running in a background thread (an oversight on my side).

Comment: You should avoid using `sleep()` in general, especially in Swift, ESPECIALLY on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

I think `NSTimer` more suitable in this case.

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree on the answer by @arsen, but I'll try to answer why this happens.

You are setting text of `UILabel`, this would indicate your code is running on the main thread. You call `sleep()` on every roll of the while loop, which in this case blocks the main thread for 90 seconds. While the main thread is blocked, UI becomes unresponsive.

It is advised that code on the main thread executes and exits as fast as possible so that the UI stays as responsive and fluid as possible.